# SQL Server select from non-existent table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, asp-classic

I have a query in classic asp where SQL statement is this:

```
Select * from active_Case
```

I verified in the DB connection it is using and found there is no such **table / view**. But a table does exist by the name of Cases. Internally it *appears* to be selecting from this table itself.

Actually this is somebody else's code. Thus I am not sure how is it possible. Is it really possible or am I missing something?

Comment: Please check is there any SYNONYM created for that table

Comment: If you are using sql server then right click on the table in schema browser and click select 200 rows. It will give you a select query, use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will give you the base table name

```
select  name, base_object_name
from    sys.synonyms 
where   name    = 'active_Case'
```

Answer (score 1):

other than tables and view you can even check in User defined table type under types. or there might be chance your table is having a schema other than 'dbo.'